# Number of states in DFA equivalent to given NFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Let's say there is a NFA with $n$ states with an alphabet consisting of $x$ symbols. I convert it to an equivalent DFA. Can I say that the number of states in the equivalent DFA is $x^n$?

Comment: This depends on how you convert it to a DFA.

Answer (score 1):

The standard powerset construction takes an NFA with $n$ states over an arbitrary alphabet and produces a DFA with $2^n$ states; this is tight for alphabets containing at least two symbols (see Chrobak's paper below for several references for this).

As for unary alphabets, Chrobak showed in his paper [Finite automata and unary languages](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82207027.pdf) that a unary NFA with $n$ states can be converted to a unary DFA with $O(e^{\sqrt{n\log n}})$ states, and showed that this is tight (up to the hidden constant factor).